# Using AWS API Gateway I have a 301 redirect, how do I include an Authorization (or other) header on that redirect?

Tags: amazon-web-services, redirect, lambda, aws-api-gateway

I am able to successfully redirect but I cannot figure out how to include headers.

Comment: You need to describe your exact scenario much more thoroughly.  If a browser sends an Authorization header, and receives a 301 response, in many cases the next request should not have the Authorization header... but it depends on the circumstances.  Perhaps a better question: Why do you have an API that returns 301?

Comment: I need to somehow transfer the `id_token` in the url fragment (not even in query string) returned on the Cognito login redirect into the `Authorization` header so that my API Gateway Cognito Authorizer can look at it and authenticate the user visiting my UI.

I assume a redirect is not the right way to go about it. @Michael-sqlbot

Comment: You should probably edit your question to explain what you are really trying to accomplish. 
 Fragments are client-side only, and not sent to the server with a request, so the only way (afaik) to work with them at all is client-side scripting.